# what some ways to mask a mysqldump?

Tags: ruby, mysql, masking

anybody knows efficiency in masking(anonymization) of some tables in a mysqldump? I have already finished my parser but unfortunately it doesn't work that good on big dumps (let say a dump of 1GB++) because it really increases the dump time due to the parsing.

what I did was parse the table columns first (which shouldn't take long) and parse the whole insert string for a specific table.

I am using ruby and would like to use it if possible.

I also looked into the idea of exporting the dump, dumping it, updating (masking) it through internal ruby code then exporting the dump again. Although I haven't tried how long this is going to take.

The current workflow for this would be:
get dump from a server, uncompress, then dump into mysql

the new one would be
get dump from a server, uncompress, masked confidential data and dump into mysql

the current workflow would take at most 2 hours for a 1-2GB++ dump but unfortunately i already spent 4hrs on the new one but it is still not finished on the parsing/masking part.

I was also advised to improvise the code by taking out variables and things that consumes more memory since the ruby gc is said to be not on a 1:1 ratio. I believe this is optimized on REE(ruby enterprise edition) but I am currently using REE also now.

Has anybody done this and maybe share their thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify tables that you don't want to dump: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table

Answer (score 8):

Years later, but might be useful for future searches (like mine). What you can do, if your structure doesn't change all the time, is to abuse the `custom where` function of mysqldump to inject SQL.

For example:

```
mysqldump -options -w "0=1 union select field1, 'constant',
anonymize(field3) from table" database table
```

This will, for a three columns table, do a dump with the first column untouched, the second set to some constant value and the third mangled with an arbitrary function.